# Seq.find returning 'a -> int instead of int

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm new with F#. I'm trying to create an F# program transforming a number to its roman numeral counterpart.

```
type RomanDigit = I | IV | V | IX
let rec romanNumeral number =
    let values = [ 9; 5; 4; 1 ]
    let toRomanDigit x =
        match x with
        | 9 -> IX
        | 5 -> V
        | 4 -> IV
        | 1 -> I
    let capture x =
        values
        |> Seq.find ( fun x -> number >= x )
    match number with
    | 0 -> []
    | int -> Seq.toList ( Seq.concat [ [ toRomanDigit capture ]; romanNumeral ( number - capture ) ] )
```

My problem here is that capture has the type 'a -> int, but I expect it to have the type int, considering Seq.find will return an int. Particularly, my subsequent calls to capture throws an error particularly in:

```
| int -> Seq.toList ( Seq.concat [ [ toRomanDigit capture ]; romanNumeral ( number - capture ) ] )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
let capture x =
    values
    |> Seq.find (fun x -> number >= x)
```

would be read as something like this:

let `capture` be a function, which given an input `x`, ignores the input and instead returns
`values |> Seq.find (fun x -> number >= x)`. So, probably you want

```
let capture = values |> Seq.find (fun x -> number >= x)
```

or

```
let capture values = values |> Seq.find (fun x -> number >= x)
```

in the latter case, it's a proper function, and you'd call it with `capture values` instead of just `capture`.

Answer (score 4):

Should `capture` be a value instead of a function? If so, remove the parameter:

```
let capture =
    values
    |> Seq.find ( fun x -> number >= x )
```